# How to linearize this objective funtion?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The objective function I am dealing is 
$$\underset{{\bf w}_k,x_k }{\max}\sum_{k=1}^K x_k\alpha_k \log_2(1+\gamma_k)$$

subject to
           $\sum x_k ||{\bf w}_k||_2^2\le P$ and

$\sum_{k=1}^Kx_k=L.$

with
$\gamma_k=\frac{|{\bf h}_k{\bf w}_k|^2}{\sigma^2+\sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^K |{\bf h}_i{\bf w}_i|^2}$.

The first constraint $\sum x_k ||{\bf w}_k||_2^2\le P$ was creating issues so I wrote it with IF-THEN form.

Here,
$x_k, k=1,2,\cdots,K$ are binary variables

$\alpha_k, k=1,2,\cdots,K$ are know positive ($>0$) numbers.

The vectors ${\bf h_k}\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times N}, k=1,2,\cdots, K$ are known.

How can I linearize them?

$\textbf{Some Tricks}$

Let's introduce $z_k,, k=1,2,\cdots,K$ as $z_k=x_k\alpha_k$

Now we have

$$\underset{{\bf w}_k }{\max}\sum_{k=1}^K z_k \log_2(1+\gamma_k)$$
$$=\underset{{\bf w}_k }{\max}\sum_{k=1}^K \log_2(1+\gamma_k)^{z_k}$$
$$=\underset{{\bf w}_k }{\max}\prod_{k=1}^K(1+\gamma_k)^{z_k}$$

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, would you please have a look at this!!

Comment: How can you expect to linearize it when you have a logarithm?

Comment: So do you even know how to deal with the underlying logarithm of a fraction of quadratics? Before you have that, there is no reason to make it more complicated (but if you do know that, you should be able to use exactly the same trick as in my answer where you introduce a new variable representing $x_k w_k$ and work with that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to represent it such that the integer relaxation is convex, one way is to note that $x\log(1+\gamma) = \log(1+x\gamma)$. Hence, all you have to do is to linearize binary times continuous, which is standard big-M representable

Here is a test using YALMIP (a MATLAB Toolbox) for a trivial example where one easily sees that the optimal solution is to set the two $x$ variables corresponding to the largest $\alpha$ to 1. The big-M modelling is done in implies, and $z$ thus corresponds to the bilinear product

```
gamma = sdpvar(5,1);
alpha = rand(5,1);
x = binvar(5,1);
z = sdpvar(5,1);
Model = [sum(x)==2, 
         implies(x,z == gamma),
         implies(1-x,z == 0),
         0 <= [z gamma] <= 1];
optimize(Model,-sum(alpha.*log2(1 + z)))
[value(x) value(alpha)]
```

The resulting model is convex in the continuous variables, and is solved in YALMIP using Mosek 9 if you have that installed, or the internal mixed-integer conic solver if you don't have Mosek 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please note that $\gamma_k$ is a function of another optimization ${\bf w}_k\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$ variable which is a complex vector. Please see the edit. You already helped me to linearize the constraint using IF-THEN linearization.

Comment: If that question really was about $\sum x_k ||{\bf w}_k||_2^2\le P$, then that answer is unnecessarily complicated. That solution is given by exactly the same strategy as here, introduce a new variable $z$ which represent $x_kw_k$, and then simple add $\sum || z_k||_2^2\le P$. There is no reason to have the 
 direction where you force the norm to be strictly positive when $x_k$ is 1

Comment: So, there is no way to approximate this objective function? Please note that I am no way looking for the optimal solution. A suboptimal formulation would be fine.

Comment: All of a sudden you talk about approximation. That has never been the topic. If you are ok with a sub-optimal solution, then any nonlinear solver with integer capabilities will do.

Comment: the reason I am talking about approximation now is that I do not want to use nonlinear solver. I am more interested in MILP formulation not on MINLP.

Comment: This model is intrinsically non-MILP:ish due to the norms